# Remove dropzone of thumbs and hide the div containing dropzone

Tags: javascript, show-hide, dropzone.js

I'm using the `dropzone.js` file uploader. Everything works fine but once I've uploaded I want to clear the dropzone of thumbs and hide the div containing dropzone. That's where things go awry. The thumbs still stay in place despite my efforts to clear them.

I've tried all the suggestions in the Dropzone.js site but nothing seems to work. I can get separate remove buttons to work using their example but can't have a master remove button. And yes, I've tried the FAQ example as well. I took the code straight from the tutorial and just added the references to the libraries and it still wouldn't remove the thumbs.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="style/dropzone.css?v=1.2" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function ClearDZ() {
            myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
            document.getElementById("container").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
<div id=container>
<form id="myDropzone" action="/target-url" class="dropzone"></form>
<button onclick="ClearDZ()">Clear All</button>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And your problem is ?

Comment: What HAVE you tried so that we're not giving duplicate suggestions you've already tried. What DOES happen when you've tried each method?

Comment: The thumbs stay visible in the dropzone form. They are supposed to be removed. When I set the display back to block, they are still there.

Comment: Actually, with the syntax as is, even the div isn't hidden. Obviously a problem at the removeAllFiles line. I have tried using the separate remove buttons in the FAQ which uses _this.removeFile(file); That works for one file at a time. I tried a variation _this.removeAllFiles(); That did exactly the same thing: Removed one file but not all. Everything else has done absolutely nothing.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder where are your dropzone configuration and how did you configure it.
If your code is as plain as you showed, you should configure your dropzone and listen to events. Try this:

```
<script>
//I'm assuming your form is called myDropzone
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
  //your configuration goes here

  init: function() {
    var myDropzone = this;

    //You can do this
    $('#your_button_id').on("click", function(e) {
      myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
    });

    //But you should do this
    this.on("success", function(file, response) {
      myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
    });

    //and this to handle any error
    this.on("error", function(file, response) {
      //handle errors here
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

You can have more information about listen to events at http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_8 and about configuration of Dropzone at http://www.dropzonejs.com/#toc_6

I hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Still not getting it to work. Here is the entire file:

Comment: Hmm. I replaced everything in <script> with your text, changed the button id to "cleardrop" on both the button and in the #your_button_id line. <button id="clearzone">Clear Dropzone</button>. No dice. I also tried the on success version and it also didn't work.

Comment: There's something I've just notice now: your div tag isn't proper closed. Did you fixed that? Which version of Dropzone are you using?

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to include jquery.js. But, seems a waste to include it just for the .on() function.

Comment: Did you try using "addEventListener" (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element.addEventListener)?

Answer (score 0):

try this on your library dropzone dropzone.js; but set time out to auto close 2500

```
success: function(file) {
    if (file.previewElement) {
      return file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success"),
      $(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.dz-success').fadeOut('slow');
        },2500);
      });
    }
  },
```